# CIB not supported: validator 'pacemaker-2.0', release '3.0.9'

Tags: ubuntu, cluster, pacemaker, corosync

I am trying to make two node clusters with pacemaker and corosync. When I want to change config with crm I get the following error:

> CIB not supported: validator 'pacemaker-2.0', release '3.0.9'

I can use crm for status and other feature but I can't change config with it. Does anyone work with pacemaker?

I use Ubuntu 15.10

Comment: No idea what "0 downvote favorite" means, but it certainly doesn't belong in the question. I edited it out for you.

Comment: @DavidMakogon This happens if one is does copy / paste (part of) a question: These are the html link titles / names of the buttons on the left hand side of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the first line/tag in your Pacemaker configuration (`# cibadmin --query > /tmp/cib.xml`) you should see something like the following:

```
<cib validate-with="pacemaker-2.0" crm_feature_set="3.0.9" ... >
```

This tells Pacemaker how to validate configurations in environments that might have mixed versions.

Without seeing the configuration you're trying to push, or knowing more about your environment, I'm not certain what the correct setting for "validate-with" would be. However, running the following command might be what you want to bring it up to something more recent:

```
# cibadmin --modify --xml-text '<cib validate-with="pacemaker-2.1"/>'
```

If you're trying with some older configuration, maybe you want this instead:

```
# cibadmin --modify --xml-text '<cib validate-with="pacemaker-1.0"/>'
```

Either way, I think this is the setting you'll want to tweak.

Comment: change to 1.2 correct it thank you so much